# REINFORCE algorithm with continuous actions (in Pytorch)?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

As the title suggests, I am trying to modify my REINFORCE algorithm, which is developed for a discrete action space environment (e.g., LunarLander-v2), to get it to work with a continuous action space environment (e.g., Pendulum-v1). I read in some blogs that in order to achieve this my model should output the mean (mu) and the variance (sigma) of a normal distribution, then sample from it, however, I cannot find an example of this.

**Here is my code for the discrete action space**, which is working fine:

```
import numpy as np
import torch as T
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, lr, input_dims, n_actions):
        super(PolicyNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(*input_dims, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, n_actions)
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=lr)

        self.device = T.device('cuda:0' if T.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self.to(self.device)

    def forward(self, state):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x

class PolicyGradientAgent():
    def __init__(self, lr, input_dims, gamma=0.99, n_actions=4):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.lr = lr
        self.reward_memory = []
        self.action_memory = []

        self.policy = PolicyNetwork(self.lr, input_dims, n_actions)

    def choose_action(self, observation):
        state = T.Tensor([observation]).to(self.policy.device)
        probabilities = F.softmax(self.policy.forward(state), dim=-1) # gives probs
        # tell pytorch whether you want categorical or continuous distribution to sample from
        action_probs = T.distributions.Categorical(probabilities) 
        action = action_probs.sample() #sample action
        log_probs = action_probs.log_prob(action) #do log of your distribution
        self.action_memory.append(log_probs) #save it 

        return action.item()

    def store_rewards(self, reward):
        self.reward_memory.append(reward)

    def learn(self):
        self.policy.optimizer.zero_grad()

        # G_t = R_t+1 + gamma * R_t+2 + gamma**2 * R_t+3 ...
        G = np.zeros_like(self.reward_memory, dtype=np.float64)
        for t in range(len(self.reward_memory)):
            G_sum = 0
            discount = 1
        # each time, G[t] = sum from current reward to the rest
            for k in range(t, len(self.reward_memory)):
                G_sum += self.reward_memory[k] * discount
                discount *= self.gamma
            #G[t] = return of each step
            G[t] = G_sum
        G = T.tensor(G, dtype=T.float).to(self.policy.device)
        
        loss = 0
        for g, logprob in zip(G, self.action_memory):
            loss += -g * logprob
        loss.backward() #compute derivatives
        self.policy.optimizer.step() #gradient step

        self.action_memory = []
        self.reward_memory = []

env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
n_games = 500  
agent = PolicyGradientAgent(gamma=0.99, lr=0.0005, input_dims=[8],
                            n_actions=4)

scores = []
for i in range(n_games):
    done = False
    observation = env.reset()
    score = 0
    while not done:
        action = agent.choose_action(observation)
        observation_, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
        env.render()
        agent.store_rewards(reward)
        observation = observation_
    agent.learn()
    scores.append(score)

env.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sample the actions from for example a gaussian distribution instead of a categorical one, given output y:

```
mean = y[:, 0:self.n_actions] # first dimension is batch dimension
# sigmoid activation keeps std positive and helps prevent explosion of values.
std = F.sigmoid(y[:, self.n_actions:2 * self.n_actions]) 
normal_distributions = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(mean, std)
sample = normal_distributions.sample()
log_probs = normal_distributions.log_prob(sample)
```

I recommend reading chapter 13.7 in this book for more details: http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf